# A slick proof of "The ring of integers of a number field has infinitely many non-associated atoms"?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbf Z_K$ be the ring of integers of an algebraic number field $K$. It is well known that $\mathbf Z_K$ has infinitely many non-associated atoms (and hence is not a [Cohen-Kaplansky domain](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939290234D)).

> **Q.** Is there a slick proof of this result? If so, could you provide a reference?

I feel the answer should be yes, but the only proof I knew until a few days ago is based on proving something much stronger and is sensibly more complicated than what I'm keen to consider a ``slick proof'': that $\mathbf Z_K$ has infinitely many prime ideals, and each of these contains a prime element.

Comment: Do you mean, there are infinitely many irreducible elements that don't differ by a unit? If so, why can't we pick the irreducible inductively? If we have $a_1,\dotsc,a_k$, then pick a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ not containing any of the $a_i$, pick an element $b \in \mathfrak{p}$, and decompose until we get $a_{k+1} \in \mathfrak{p}$ irreducible.

Comment: @DongryulKim Maybe I'm being slow, but how do you know in the first place that such a prime ideal  does exist? Are you basically trying to reproduce Euclid's proof of the infinitude of rational primes? Something like, ``Assume to the contrary that there are only finitely many pairwise non-associated atoms $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and look at the factorizations of $a_1 \cdots a_n+1$". But the problem with this argument is that one should guarantee that $a_1\cdots a_n+1$ isn't going to be a unit.

Comment: (1) For the existence of $\mathfrak{p}$, here's what I'm doing. Given any nonzero number $a$, there exist only finitely many prime ideals containing $a$. So given a finite number of $a_i$, I can find a prime not containing any of them. (2) I guess the spirit is similar to Euclid's proof, but it's slightly different. I already know that there are infinitely many prime ideals, and I'm using it to run the argument.

Comment: @DongryulKim I see, and this is slicker than what I had in mind, since the existence of infinitely many prime ideals in $\mathbf Z_K$ has a rather straightforward proof (somehow I had convinced myself that this wouldn't have been enough and I would have also needed to know that each prime ideal contains a prime element). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fact 1.** The ring $\textbf{Z}_K$ has infinitely many prime ideals and has Krull dimension $1$.

**Proof.** We have a surjective morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,\textbf{Z}_K\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$. This follows from the fact that the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \textbf{Z}_K$ is an integral extension of rings. So it suffices to invoke the going-up theorem of Cohen-Seidenberg. There is at least one prime ideal of $\textbf{Z}_K$ in each fiber of the morphism.

**Fact 2.** Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain. Then every nonzero and non-invertible element $a\in A$ can be decomposed as

$$a = f_1\cdot f_2\cdot ...\cdot f_n$$

where $f_1,...,f_n\in A$ are irreducible.

**Proof.** Fix $a\in A$ as in the statement. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of proper principial ideals of $A$ that contain $a$. Since $A$ is Noetherian, in $\mathcal{F}$ there exists a maximal element with respect to inclusion. Say that this maximal element is generated by some $f_1\in A$. Then $a = f_1\cdot a_1$. If $a_1$ is non-invertible apply this argument to $a_1$ and obtain $f_2$ and $a_2$. In other words, continue by induction. It is clear that

1. All $f_1,f_2,...$ are irreducible (otherwise ideals generate by them won't be maximal among principial ideals).
2. This procedure must stop at some point. Indeed, $a_{n+1}$ must be invertible for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, since otherwise you will obtain infinite and increasing chain of ideals $Aa_1\subseteq Aa_2\subseteq ...\subseteq Aa_n\subseteq ...$ in the Noetherian ring $A$.

This implies that $a = f_1\cdot f_2\cdot ...\cdot f_n$.

**Remark.**
The decomposition in **Fact 2** is by no means unique.

**Corollary.** All nonzero prime ideals of $\textbf{Z}_K$ are maximal.

Now you can construct infinite sequence of irreducible elements of $\textbf{Z}_K$ as follows. Pick $\{\mathfrak{p}_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of pairwise distinct maximal ideals in $\textbf{Z}_K$. This is possible by **Fact 1** and **Corollary**. [**Prime avoidance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma) shows that

$$\mathfrak{p}_{n+1}\subsetneq \bigcup_{k=0}^n\mathfrak{p}_k$$

Hence for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists 
$$r_{n+1}\in \mathfrak{p}_{n + 1}\setminus \left(\bigcup_{k=0}^n\mathfrak{p}_k\right)$$

and by virtue of **Fact 2** you may pick irreducible divisor $f_{n+1}$ of $r_{n+1}$ in $\mathfrak{p}_{n+1}$. You still have that 
$$f_{n+1}\in \mathfrak{p}_{n + 1}\setminus \left(\bigcup_{k=0}^n\mathfrak{p}_k\right)$$
and hence $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are irreducible elements of $\textbf{Z}_K$ such that no two differ by unit.

This actually proves the following.

**Proposition.** Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain with infinitely many maximal ideals, then $A$ contains an infinite set of irreducible elements such that no two differ by unit.

**Remark.** If $A$ is a Dedekind ring with finitely many prime ideals, then one can prove that $A$ is a UFD and hence the proposition above does not hold.